# In a previous life, I worked at Delaware

Tags: bug, jobs

When you go to add experience on your Careers profile the field for Organization is actually called "Location," leading Chrome's autocomplete to believe that I used to work for a physical place. For example:

[image: Chrome autocomplete on the organization field]

Admittedly this is fairly minor, but the field should probably be called something like "Organization" to avoid this. There's also the issue of this form being repeated in the source multiple times (once per experience item), resulting in various elements with the same ID attribute, but that doesn't actually cause any usability problems.