# Change "Login" to "Log in" and "Logout" to "Log out"

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

OK, so not a bug *per se*, but it does 'bug' me...

On the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) page, the link to log in is labelled **login** rather than **log in**. The latter is on all the other SE sites I clicked through to, so why not the Data Explorer?

After all, [LoginIsNotAVerb.com](http://loginisnotaverb.com/)!

*EDIT 1:* Also noticed that when logged in to any SE site, the link to log out is labelled  **logout**, but should be **log out**. Hover over your username to see this link in the summary that pops up.

*EDIT 2:* Just to clarify, this question is ***not*** about whether "login" and "logout" are verbs - I think [that's pretty well-defined already](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to). The question is **can we make sure the correct forms of *log in* and *log out* are used consistently across all the Stack Exchange sites?**

Comment: There's no rule that says links must be verbs, so I'm not sure how that last link is relevant. I do support cross-site consistency, though.

Comment: This isn't only on the Data Explorer...

Comment: @PopularDemand Because you're clicking it to log in. Not to login. For the same reason, when you're logged in it should say **Log Out**, not **Logout**.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a rule either - more of a heuristic...

Comment: How do you feel about the "tools" link? Or "faq"? "meta"?

Comment: I feel very happy about them indeed because they take me to the destinations they promise (they're all nouns). Login doesn't take me to my login, which makes me sad. It does take me to a place where I can log in, however.

Comment: Disagree.  Look at the phrase **"Log In"**.  What the hell does that mean?  You aren't "logging" anything; the system may, but what you are doing is providing information that the system uses to authenticate your identity.  The phrase doesn't describe what you are doing.  It is a holdover from an older time when persons would enter their name in a "log".  Names like "Richard Head" and "Maidik Gozinya", if my memory of childhood is accurate.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ - Replace 'log' with 'clock'; do you think it should be "clockin" because you aren't "clocking" anything? Plus, if 'login' was a verb, you'd not be _logging in_, but _logining_. Eww. Or, you'd have just _logined_ instead of _logged in_.

Comment: @Widor: Who said anything about clockin?  My point is that "log in" is no better, if not worse than, "login".  At least "login" is a new word for a new concept.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ - 'log in' and 'clock in' are the same construct. Same with 'check out'. You _check out_ at the **checkout**, you _log in_ at the **login** page. If you believe 'login' is a valid verb, then you have to accept 'clockin' too. If I humour you for a moment and say that 'login' is now a verb, can you suggest what you think the past tense of it should be?

Comment: This really seems to be bug(g)in' you ... `;)`

Comment: @Widor: Actually, I don't have to accept anything, thanks.  It *is* still just an opinion.  Otherwise, you'd have to accept that I am 100% correct.  Nyah.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ You can't claim that classification of verbs and nouns is subject to personal opinion!

Comment: If it should be **Log in** shouldn't it be **Log out** (with a small "o" on out) instead of **Log Out** then?

Comment: Well done meta. Widor put the "trivial bugs get the most upvotes" theory to the ultimate test, and we didn't disappoint

Comment: @Michael -- a little bit of wit and humor, combined with a little bit of grammar nerdishness will get me to reach for the upvote button every time.  I can't speak for the rest of the community though.

Comment: @Jonas Yes, have edited accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek What, are you implying that [You got your double-encoded space in my tooltip](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94051) and [In a previous life, I worked at Delaware](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100156) weren't critical bugs?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - I agree wholeheartedly. Let's not waste time on my trivial suggestions when [THERE ARE DIAMONDS MISSING!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65773/image-based-flair-doesnt-include-diamond)

Comment: @Widor Excuse me? That was useful -- I use the accounts tab all the time to check if a user is a mod on any network sites, and at the time the accounts tab showed user flair, so not showing a diamond made it much harder to determine if a user was a mod

Comment: @MichaelMrozek My point - as you have ably demonstrated - is that what is trivial to one may be important to another. Implying that my minor suggestion was just a deliberate lowest-common-denominator, rep-grabbing race to the bottom is actually a little hurtful to be honest :-(

Comment: @Widor I didn't mean to imply that you posted this to get rep, I'm sure it does matter to you; I was making fun of meta for upvoting bugs that are easy to understand instead of bugs that are problematic. I absolutely did mean to imply it was trivial though -- a link saying "login" instead of "log in" is not dramatically affecting your usage of the site. It's not like reporting it was bad, I just find 17 upvotes for something like this to be absurd

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Sure, I can use the site just fine, but for me it's a prominent user-experience niggle. You know that feeling you get when someone calls you "Micheal"? If you do, it's like that. And yep, it's trivial and populist but hey, so are all the best UX features.

Comment: This will be fixed on Stack Exchange next build.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Thanks, I'll look forward to it :-)

Comment: This is being fixed in Data Explorer too by the way, but the ETA will be a tiny bit longer.

Comment: @TimStone Appreciated also.

Comment: [If login isn't a verb yet, it will be soon.](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2393) Cope.

Comment: @Jarrod, mobile might need the same love ;-) (Both in the menu, and in the dialog that pops up when trying to vote when not logged in.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completed in the Data Explorer trunk: http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/

It may take a few weeks till this goes live, lots changed and we need to stabilize it first.